# How can I check to see if all items in a set have been scanned using dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, global, os.walk

I have a script that scans files using os.walk.
Each file name has data that I pull out of the filename (eg time stamps)
Each file belongs to a set of 10.
for example:

- treepicture_01.jpg
- treepicture_02.jpg
- carpicture_08.jpg
- etc

After all files are scanned, I need to check each group of files ('treepicture' or 'carpicture' in the example) and see if the set is complete. (i.e., do I have 'treepicture_01" through "treepicture_10"? and if not, which ones am I missing?)

My approach to this so far has been attempting to build dictionaries and using the timestamps as the keys and the string 'found' for the value if the timestamp is found.

This block happens inside the scanning function:

```
    if uniqueAngle not in allUniqueAngles:
                allUniqueAngles.append(uniqueAngle)
                global (exec(uniqueAngle)) = {}
                exec(uniqueAngle)[timeEntry] = 'found'
```

Then outside of the scanning function I want something like this:

```
for uniqueAngle in allUniqueAngles:
     if uniqueAngle[timeEntry] = 'found'
          print('Yay!')
```

I obviously haven't been able to test this, because as I'm sure you've noticed

```
global (exec(uniqueAngle)) = {}
```

won't compile.

So my **first question** is, should I use
`exec(uniqueAngle)`
to create a dictionary with a unique name for every group of pictures? So I'd end up with:

```
treepicture
['01':'found','02':'found]
```

I personally can't come up with another way.

**Second question**, if that is an acceptable way to manage the dictionaries, how do I make sure I can access those dictionaries from outside the function? I.e., how do I make my dictionary that gets created inside a function global?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "is, should I use exec(uniqueAngle) to create a dictionary with a unique name for every group of pictures? " no, you absolutely should not be creating dynamic variables. That is essentially always a bad practice

Comment: " how do I make my dictionary that gets created inside a function global?" *objects are neither global nor local*. That is a category error. *Variables* are global or local. The most basic way to make some object inside a function accessible outside is to *return that object* from the function.

Comment: thank you juanpa! Any thoughts as to how I can accomplish my goal without using dynamic variables? Even a starting point?

Comment: Use a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dictionary where the key is your timestamp ("car", "tree" in your example) and the value is a list of the found files.

The following code works on  a "dummy" input list for brevity, but the interesting part is in the last few lines

```
from collections import defaultdict

dummyinput = ['car01.jpg','car02.jpg','car03.jpg','car05.jpg','car08.jpg',
              'tree01.jpg','tree02.jpg','tree03.jpg','tree04.jpg','tree05.jpg']
found = defaultdict(list)
maxnumber = 10

def splitname(name):
    simplename = name.split('.')[0]
    return (simplename[:-2], int(simplename[-2:]))

for dummy in dummyinput:
    k, number = splitname(dummy)
    found[k].append(number)

for k in found:
    print(f'missing {[x for x in range(1,maxnumber+1) if x not in found[k]]} for key {k}')
----
missing [4, 6, 7, 9, 10] for key car
missing [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] for key tree
```

Comment: I really appreciate you sharing this with me!
I'll have to decompress some of it for myself, but it looks like it's what I need.